# How to start a new row number every time, when there is a change in value(+ve/-ve) from the preceding row in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

How to start a new row number every time, when there is a change in value(+ve/-ve) from the preceding row

```
xcol  rownumcol
----  ---------
-1    1
-1    2
1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
1     2
1     3
-1    1         --start of new rownumber/series
1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
-1    1         --start of new rownumber/series
1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
1     2
```

Being new to SQL Server, I'm not able to figure out how to solve this. however, I have tried using `ROW_NUMBER()` CASE statement, but it is kinda becoming too hardcoded and not having consistency, please help me achieve the desired output.

Also tried LEAD and LAG functions inside CASE statement.

```
OId   xcol  rownumcol
---   ----  ---------
1    -1     1
2    -1     2
3     1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
4     1     2
5     1     3
6    -1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
7     1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
8    -1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
9     1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
10    1     2

a_id        OId         datecol    amt                                     Xcol
----------- ----------- ---------- --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
1           9997        2014-03-18 99.17                                   1.00
1           9981        2014-03-16 71.44                                   1.00
1           9979        2014-03-16 -94.60                                  -1.00
1           9977        2014-03-16 -6.96                                   -1.00
1           9971        2014-03-15 -65.95                                  -1.00
1           9964        2014-03-15 15.13                                   1.00
1           9962        2014-03-15 17.47                                   1.00
1           9960        2014-03-15 -3.55                                   -1.00
1           9959        2014-03-14 32.00                                   1.00
1           9957        2014-03-14 -30.00                                  -1.00
1           9954        2014-03-13 -5.56                                   -1.00
```

Comment: Yes there is an Id column as follows:

OId xcol  rownumcol
---   ----    ---------
1    -1     1
2    -1     2
3     1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
4     1     2
5     1     3
6    -1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
7     1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
8    -1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
9     1     1         --start of new rownumber/series
10   1     2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                IIF([xcol] = LAG([xcol]) OVER (ORDER BY OId), 0, 1) AS GrpFlag
         FROM   YourTable),
    T2 AS ( SELECT  * ,
                  SUM(GrpFlag) OVER (ORDER BY OId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS Grp
         FROM     T1 )
SELECT   OId,
         xcol,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Grp ORDER BY OId) AS rownumcol
FROM     T2
```

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/5e8f3/1)

Or, another...

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT *,
                IIF([xcol] = LAG([xcol]) OVER (ORDER BY OId), 0, 1) AS GrpFlag,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY OID) AS OriginalRn
         FROM   YourTable)
SELECT *,
       1 + OriginalRn - MAX(CASE WHEN GrpFlag = 1 THEN OriginalRn END) OVER (ORDER BY OId ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)
FROM T1
```

Comment: @Roj44 Instead of posting a thanking comment you should accept the answer see how at https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work